# How do you dynamically display user profiles?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, yii

This may very well have been asked before, but I could not find it.

I am building a page for users to browse other user's profiles. My current plan is for the profiles to be displayed in order of when they were last displayed and when they were last online.

So pretty much I give each item which resides in a database an attribute of last_displayed which contains a timestamp of when the profile was last displayed. Once a profile is displayed the timestamp will be updated and it will not be displayed until other profiles with older last_displayed timestamps are displayed.

At the same time there will be a last_online attribute which contains a timestamp of when the profile was last online. This is to show the more recently online users before showing the older users.

Now when actually querying the database for profiles to display I widen the range of last_displayed and last_online until sufficient profiles are found.

I assume this functionality is not unlike that of dating sites.

So my question is this: Is there a better way to dynamically display user profiles?

Thanks for reading if you got this far!

Comment: I don't really have any improvements to make on your db design. Why do you widen the range until sufficient profiles are found, though? Shouldn't a `ORDER BY last_online LIMIT $num` do the work?

Comment: @TheWolf Well I want it to be ordered by the last_online AND last_displayed. This way if a profile was last_online very recently but last_displayed a long time ago, it should be displayed before a profile that was last_online recently and last_displayed recently as well. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have you developed a formula to determine the exact order the users shall be displayed in? If this formula is not too complicated, you might be able to let MySQL do the work of choosing the users and putting them in order.

Comment: Right now the formula involves increasing a single digit which directly increases the range of last_online and last_displayed. The rate at which these ranges are increased still need some tweaking, but the functionality is there. This range is looped through and increased until sufficient profiles are found. I will look into seeing if mySQL can do more work for me though. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Put a piece of SQL here or link to http://sqlfiddle.com/ — it's mostly about this.

You must not use here any range wides — you should found some satisfactory column / order combination to have simple `ORDER BY $columns LIMIT $num`

In this schema you can use in `$columns` something like: `column1 DESC, column2 DESC` or vice versa
Or may be their combination like: `IFNULL(column1, column2)` or `MAX(column1, column2)`.

Go in this direction. When you found the right solution — publish it here.

ps: I suggest you to remove here yii tag.